# Spring boot data filtering with List/Set

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a table that shows names, emails and so but also lists like which roles or competences a certain user has.

I'm having trouble filtering the table using for example the roles array. One user can have many roles and the table shows that. I need to be able to filter by selecting for example two roles: "Service manager" and "Logistics manager". Server response should be all users with those roles.

Controller function for getting filtered users:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('service_manager')")
    @RequestMapping(path = "/workers", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Page<WorkDetailResponse> getWorkers(
            @RequestParam(defaultValue = "0") Integer page,
            @RequestParam(defaultValue = "10") Integer size,
            @RequestParam(required = false) String name,
            @RequestParam(required = false) BigInteger phone,
            @RequestParam(required = false) String email,
            @RequestParam(required = false) Set<Competence> competences,
            @RequestParam(required = false) Set<UserRole> roles,
            @RequestParam(required = false) User.UserStatus status,
            @RequestParam(defaultValue = "createTime") String sort,
            @RequestParam(defaultValue = "desc") String sortDir
            ){

        WorkDetailListRequest request = new WorkDetailListRequest(name, phone, email, competences, roles, status);

        Sort.Direction direction;

        if (sortDir.equals("asc")) {
            direction = Sort.Direction.ASC;
        } else {
            direction = Sort.Direction.DESC;
        }

        return workDetailService.getWorkDetails(request, of(page, size, direction, sort))
                .map(WorkDetailResponse::new);
    }
```

This is the service function:

```
public Page<WorkDetail> getWorkDetails(WorkDetailListRequest request, Pageable pageable) {
        Specification<WorkDetail> spec = where(null);

        if (request.getName() != null) spec = spec.and(name(request.getName()));
        if (request.getPhone() != null) spec = spec.and(phoneOne(request.getPhone()));
        if (request.getEmail() != null) spec = spec.and(email(request.getName()));
        if (request.getCompetences() != null) spec = spec.and(competences(request.getCompetences()));
        if (request.getRoles() != null) spec = spec.and(roles(request.getRoles()));
        if (request.getStatus() != null) spec = spec.and(status(request.getStatus()));

        return workDetailRepository.findAll(spec, pageable);
    }
```

This is the specification for the roles:

```
public static Specification<WorkDetail> roles(Set<UserRole> roles) {
        return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("user").get("roles"), roles);
    }
```

Currently when I send role objects from my front end it sends them as string and Spring boot throws an error 
`Failed to convert value of type 'java.Lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Set'`

Answer (score 0):

you trying to create a query like

> select * from table where roles equal 'a','b','c'

this is invalid Query.

for solving your problem use in

```
criteriaBuilder.in(root.get("user").get("roles"), roles)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

After changing my specification to that it now says:
in (Expression<?>) in criteriabuilder cannot be applied to (Path<Object>)

Comment: Expression attribute= root.get("user").get("roles"); attribute.in((Set) roles) you need something like this

Comment: Not really, the "root" after attribute = says "Cannot resolve symbol root"